# Send extra String data with the PJSUA2 call while making a call

Tags: android, pjsua2

I am implementing PJSUA2 in my app. Once the user makes a call, I am trying to add one extra String variable to the CallOpParam object, which is returning "" at the receiving side. Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks in advance.
I have tried the setReason() method of CallOpParam object to send data.